# Cumulative Revenue

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

What am I missing here why is my cumulative revenue not getting calculated

[image]

```
Cumulative_Revenue_By_PurchaseMonth = CALCULATE(('Revenue Stats KPIs'[Revenue]), FILTER(ALL(DimDatePayment[Calendar Month Year]), DimDatePayment[Calendar Month Year] <= MAX(DimDatePayment[Calendar Month Year])))
```

there is relationship between the DimDatePayment and Revenue Stats but still its not calculating correctly. kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I did this on AW2012DW:

```
RT Sales Qty = 
CALCULATE( [Total Qty], 
FILTER( ALL('DimDate'), 'DimDate'[MonthYear] <= MAX('DimDate'[MonthYear]) && 'DimDate'[CalendarYear] = MAX('DimDate'[CalendarYear]) ) )
```

Things I would check:

1. There's a relationship between DimDate and your Fact table.
2. Use the date/columns from the date dimension table instead of the fact table in your visuals.

Comment: I checked there is relationship existing between  the fact and Dim table, also I am using the Date columns from the Dim Date.

Comment: What other checks can I do? it is still not creating the cumulative Aggregation.

Comment: I created a new model with just one table (MoYr, Revenue) where MoYr is the first of each month (1 jan 2023, 1 feb 2023 etc). Then these are my measures. Still works.

Total Revenue:= SUM('Table1'[Revenue])
RT Revenue := CALCULATE([Total Revenue],
 FILTER( ALL('Table1'), Table1[MoYr]<=MAX('Table1'[MoYr]) ) 
)